# ASP.NET Page Canonical Tag URL Protocol Changes Unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

I need help with a weird problem. I have an .aspx page where I'm placing the canonical URL of the page like this:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/page.aspx" />`

When I access the page via HTTP it displays exactly as expected, but when I access it via HTTPS, the text in the canonical *href* attribute changes to HTTPS. I don't want that, I want it just as I wrote it there HTTP

Is it possible that the .NET configuration does this? I don't find anything that could cause it. Is there a setting in IIS? Where should I look?

- I've tried writing a custom text in the value of href and it displays the as expected both on HTTP and HTTPS
- I've tried writing the *https://* version in the href and it displays it as expected (https) both on HTTP and HTTPS
- I've tried writing "//:link" (without the protocol) and it displays "//:link" on both HTTP and HTTPS

So to summarize the question, how do I get the canonical tag to display "http://" when I access it via HTTPS?

I've been  banging my head on the walls for the last 2 days about this issue and can't figure it out.

Please help!

Comment: Not sure, but i'm thinking your web server is auto redirecting http to https? Check the netork tab of the element inspector, you should see a 302 that redirects to https if i'm right.

Comment: No, it's not about redirects. It's the source of the page that gets altered from what I am putting in the code of the .aspx